# multiple percentile_cont with where clause

Tags: sql-server, azure-sql-database, sql-server-2019

I'm using percentile_cont to find 50th percentile of product that is sold and product that is open to sell using where clause. Sale is a big table and it is creating performance issues. **Is it possible to modify the following query such that the Sale is accessed only once and we can get both the percentiles?**
I **cannot use CTE** due to application limitations. User writes ad-hoc queries and application converts it to SQL code. But it will have access to only set of entities and few functions like CTE is not supported. Sub queries are supported though.

Query :

```
SELECT   p.ProductId,
         p.Name AS ProductName,
         login_previous_period.LastLoginDate AS previous_login_date,
         COALESCE (MedianAge, 0) AS SalesAgeMedian,
         COALESCE (AVG(CASE WHEN i.State = 'Sold' THEN DATEDIFF(day, i.CreatedDate, i.SoldDate) ELSE NULL END), 0) AS SalesTimeToSell,
         COALESCE (MedianTimeToSell, 0) AS SalesTimeToSellMedian
FROM     Product AS p
         LEFT OUTER JOIN
         (SELECT   ProductId,
                   MAX(LoginDate) AS LastLoginDate
          FROM     Customer
          WHERE    LoginDate <= DATEADD(day, -7, GETUTCDATE())
          GROUP BY ProductId) AS login_previous_period
         ON p.ProductId = login_previous_period.ProductId
         LEFT OUTER JOIN
         (SELECT DISTINCT productOpen.ProductId,
                          percentile_cont(0.5) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY saleOpen.DateKey) OVER (PARTITION BY productOpen.ProductId) AS MedianAge
          FROM   Product AS productOpen 
                 LEFT OUTER JOIN
                 Sale AS saleOpen -- access to Sale table number 1
                 ON productOpen.ProductId = saleOpen.ProductId
          WHERE  productOpen.Active = 1
                 AND saleOpen.State = 'Open') AS openIss
         ON p.ProductId = openIss.ProductId
         LEFT OUTER JOIN
         (SELECT DISTINCT productSold.ProductId,
                          percentile_cont(0.5) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY (DATEDIFF(day, productSoldCreatedDate, productSoldSoldDate))) OVER (PARTITION BY productSold.ProductId) AS MedianTimeToSell
          FROM   Product AS productSold 
                 LEFT OUTER JOIN
                 Sale AS productSold -- access to Sale table number 2
                 ON productSold.ProductId = productSoldProductId
          WHERE  productSold.Active = 1
                 AND productSoldState = 'Sold' ) AS SoldIss
         ON p.ProductId = SoldIss.ProductId
WHERE    p.Valid = 1
GROUP BY p.ProductId, openIss.MedianAge, SoldIss.MedianTimeToSell, activity_previous_period.LastLoginDate
ORDER BY p.Name;
```

The only difference between both the queries with Sale table is

```
AND productSoldState = 'Sold'
```

Comment: "*I cannot use CTE due to application limitation*" - Why?...I don't believe any application can limit whether you're able to use a CTE or not. Please elaborate. Also please run your query with the actual execution plan turned on, upload the execution plan to [Paste The Plan](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan), and link it in your Post.

Comment: @J.D. The SQL layer is on top of the application which doesn't parse CTE.

Comment: "*The SQL layer is on top of the application...*" - That doesn't make a ton of sense, could you please elaborate further?...are you saying you write your SQL code inside of the application itself?

Comment: @J.D. To elaborate, user doesn't have liberty to use all the possible functions of SQL server like CTE. User query is transformed into SQL server query in the application layer. The transformation here limits the use of CTE.

Comment: Can the application select from views? Is the process basically the user writes a query ad-hocly and the application converts it to SQL code? It looks like it supports subqueries?

Comment: @J.D. that's correct. user writes ad-hoc queries and application converts it to SQL code. But it will have access to only set of entities. Subqueries are supported.

Comment: @J.D. My question is more around how can we have percentile_cont with where clause so that multiple percentile_cont can be used with multiple where clause using a single access to table/view. Something like CASE.

Comment: Right, I understand. It's just important knowing the details of the limitations though so we know what solutions we can provide. You may want to add the responses to my previous questions to your main post so other people are aware or the limitations. Note it's a difficult process to optimize performance for ad-hoc user generated queries. You still should provide the execution plan of the example query you provided, as that'll help us answer your question. Also please provide the index definitions for all of the tables used in that query.

Comment: Can't you create a Stored Procedure or Function containing the functionality you need? Then you might be able to use a CTE or other way to select your data.

Answer (score -1):

Try to move from `percentile_cont` to  `APPROX_PERCENTILE_CONT`

In this [example](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/azure-sql-blog/announcing-general-availability-of-approximate-percentile/bc-p/3773395/emcs_t/S2h8ZW1haWx8dG9waWNfc3Vic2NyaXB0aW9ufExGSUlVOThXWDE4QzYxfDM3NzMzOTV8U1VCU0NSSVBUSU9OU3xoSw#M1377) it pushed the speed from ~13 seconds to ~1.5 seconds.